# How to test a service that is called on .success of http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-http

I have a controller that calls a service that performs a `http.post` with a username and password. On .success of the post, i call another service to create a cookie.

I 'believe' i have created a successful Jasmine test to test the POST, but unsure of how i then test the cookie service.

**LoginController.js:**

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http, signInService, cookieSrv) {

    $scope.LogIn = function(usrnm, pwd) {
        signInService.authUser(usrnm, pwd)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                var cookieID = 'myCookie';
                cookieSrv.createCookie(cookieID, data.token, 3, data.redirectUrl);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               // Display error message
            }
    }
});
```

**cookieSrv.js**

```
app.service('cookieSrv', function() {
    return {
        createCookie : function(cookieID, token, days, redirectUrl) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = cookieID+"="+token+expires+"; path=/";

            window.location.assign(redirectUrl)
        }
    }
});
```

**signInService:**

```
app.service('signInService', function($http) {    
    this.authUser = function (usrnm, pwd) {    
        return $http.post('/api/json/authenticate', {}, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-app-Username': usrnm,
                'X-app-Password': pwd
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Unit test:

```
describe('Controller: LoginController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, signInService, $httpBackend){
        this.$httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('LoginController', {
            $scope: this.scope,
            localSignInService: signInService
        });
    }));    

    describe("successfully logged in", function() {
        it("should redirect to home", function() {

            var fakeResponse = {
                access_token: 'myToken'
            }

            this.$httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/json/authenticate', {} , function(headers) {
                return {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-app-Username': 'tomcat',
                    'X-app-Password': 'tomcat'
                };
            }).respond(200, fakeResponse);

            this.scope.LogIn("tomcat","tomcat");
            this.$httpBackend.flush();
            expect(fakeResponse.access_token).toEqual("myToken");
        });
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

With the above i am getting the error:

```
ERROR Some of your tests did a full page reload!
```

Some research suggests this is because of the `window.location.assign` in the cookie service. If i comment out this line, the test runs fine without the error above.